# Cannot access 'auth' before initialization in Firebase 9.x

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I'm trying to set up Firebase authentication for a Next.js app. I'm using Firebase 9.6.4. I can't figure out the modular importing in v9, and I'm getting this error when accessing the route `/api/login`.

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'auth' before initialization
```

Here is the relevant code:

*lib/firebase.js*

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = { ... };

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, "App Name");

export const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export default firebase;
```

*pages/api/login.js*

```js
import firebase, { auth, provider } from "../../lib/firebase";

export default function signIn(req, res) {
  auth
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(...)
    .catch(...);
}
...
```

Comment: Have you tried renaming `lib/firebase.js` to something else?

Comment: I have tried it without success.